# How do I change the tab placement highlight color in vscode?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

How do I change the tab placement highlight color in vscode? In the image below I am moving the css file to the bottom half of the screen and The highlight color (red) shows where the tab is going to be moved to. I want to change the color of where the tab is going to be moved, is that possible in settings.json?

[image: Tab placement highlight color(red)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editorGroup.dropBackground": "#ff0000"  // change this color
}
```

looks like the one you want (it uses gray in my colorTheme by default).  There are some other `drop` colors you can modify.  Just start typing `drop` in a `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` in your settings to see the suggestions of other possibilities.